# Programmatically change the data sources in a Power BI file

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powershell-3.0

I need to use PowerShell to change the **paths** of the data sources of a **local** Power BI report file.
For example, I want to change the data source path from `C:\.....\sales.csv` to `D:\.....\sales_new.csv`

[image]

I have found this [four-year-old response](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Change-pbix-data-source-programmatically/m-p/129735/highlight/true#M55227) to a quite similar question.
I have followed the instructions and it is working quite fine.
The only problem is that I need to refresh the Power BI report **manually** everytime after I changed the data source paths within the xml-file. With the term "manually refreshing" I mean that someone needs to open each Power BI file and confirm the refreshing of the data sources.

It is unsatisfying for my customer to manually refresh each Power BI report after altering the data source paths within the xml-file.

I have also read about the possibility, to change the ending a Power BI report file from *.pbix to *.zip, to extract it and open the "Connections" file to modify the path stored inside this file.

[image]

However, when I open the "Connections" file with Notepad, there is no data source path, like `C:\.....\sales.csv`, in this file.

[image]

Is there any way how I can programmatically change the data source paths in a **local** Power BI report file without the need to manually refresh the Power BI file after changing the data source path?

Comment: Local PBIX files don't automatically refresh their data ever, whether you change the data source to point to different files, or just update the existing data files.

Comment: Can I do the "refreshing of the new data" with PowerShell?
I mean, can I open the Power BI report and confirm the refreshing with PowerShell?

Comment: There is no supported automation interface for Power BI Desktop, which is a free tool for development and small-team local colaboration.  All the automation APIs are part of the Power BI Service.  Although like any desktop app, you can build something with Robotic Process Automation, eg Power Automate Desktop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helped me in solving my problem:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-does-not-resolve-parameters-for-connection/m-p/2115774/highlight/true#M783462

It is not changing the data source path of a **local** report, as I asked, but on a Report which is stored in a Power BI Report Server.